# Dask graph: Color tasks by layers

Tags: python, visualization, dask, graphviz

In Dask, I can visualize either HighLevelGraphs or the (low-level) Dask objects.

```py
df = dask.datasets.timeseries(end='2000-04-01', partition_freq='1m')
df['x'] = df['x'] * 2
```

##### HighLevelGraph

```py
df.dask.visualize()
```

[image: Dask HighLevelGraph]

#### Low-level graph

```py
df.visualize(size="7")
```

[image: Dask low-level graph]

#### Question

In this simple example, it's easy to tell which (low-level graph) tasks belong to which layer.

In more complex workflows, the low-level graph is often huge and confusing. It would be of great help if I could color the nodes by the layer they belong to. Ideally, I could also apply the same coloring to the high level graph visualization.

Is this possible, and if so, then how?

#### Solution attempt

I am aware of the `color` argument of both visualizations, but the available options, that is

- `layer_type` for HighLevelGraph
- `order` for low-level dask graph

do not let me see which low-level task belongs to which layer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `color` kwarg, for example:

```py
df.dask.visualize(color='layer_type') # high-level graph
df.visualize(color='order') # low-level graph
# also note that optimize_graph=True is a true representation
# of the order in which tasks are executed
```

Note that for the order visualisation it's possible to pass additional options, see example in [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/order.html).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of these options, but they do not solve my problem, as far as I can tell. Sorry, I could've been clearer about this, I have added it to the question.

Comment: Ah, ok, the docs recommend selecting specific parts of the low level graph (when that is feasible).

Comment: Could you give me an example or link to the docs you're referring to, please?

Comment: see the link: "As usual with dask.visualize, you may need to trim down the problem to a smaller size, so we’ll slice off a subset of the data."